# Vue js Swiper Element - Malfunction when updating the number of slides

Tags: vue.js, user-interface, vuetify.js, swiper.js

I'm currently working on a project requiring the use of a swiper to display a fairly large number of slides (150+). I've chosen this tool: https://swiperjs.com/element

The interface can be used on both desktop and mobile devices. So many slides on a mobile device can quickly become complicated to use, so I've added the ability to filter the slides displayed on the screen, here is a jsfiddle for the exemple : [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Glow_Jr/0m4j51fL/51/)

I've changed the number of slides displayed on the screen according to the screen size and so far everything seems to be working.

The problem is this, somewhat randomly but inevitably, as soon as I filter the list with the buttons above or change the window size, or both, the slider no longer works properly, either the scrollbar extends far too far in relation to the number of slides displayed, or some slides take up too much width trying to fit something. And sometimes, the scrollbar disappears even though there are slides off-screen.

[Slide size malfunction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AGRl.png)
[Swiper size/scrollbar malfunction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aftVP.png)

(I let you manipulate the js fiddle to reproduce)

```
<div id="demo">
  <div class="text-center">
    <v-btn-toggle v-model="selectedMedia"
                  mandatory active-class="selectedMedia" dense >
      <v-btn :value="null">
        <span>All</span>
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn v-for="media in listAllMedia" :value="media.code" :key="media.code">
        <span>{{media.label}}</span>
      </v-btn>
    </v-btn-toggle>
  </div>

  <swiper-container ref="swiper" :slides-per-view="isMobile ? 2 : 10"
                    :space-between="isMobile ? 5 : 10"
                    :centered-slides="false"
                    :scrollbar="true" 
                    :scrollbar-draggable="true" 
                    :scrollbar-drag-size="isMobile ? 50 : 100" 
                    :free-mode="true"
                    
                    breakpoints='{"100": {"slidesPerView": 2}, "480": {"slidesPerView": 3}, "650": {"slidesPerView": 4}, "850": {"slidesPerView": 5}, "950": {"slidesPerView": 6}, "1150": {"slidesPerView": 7}, "1300": {"slidesPerView": 8}, "1500": {"slidesPerView": 9}, "1700": {"slidesPerView": 10}}'>

    <template v-for="chara in filteredListCharacters">
      <swiper-slide>
        <v-card style="height: 300px; border: 1px solid black">

          <v-card-title style="color: black; padding-top: 10px;">{{chara.name}}
          </v-card-title>

          <v-card-text style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;">
            <div v-for="media in chara.medias" style="font-style: italic; color: gray; font-size: 10px;">{{listAllMedia.filter(x => x.code == media)[0]?.label}}</div>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </swiper-slide>
    </template>
  </swiper-container>
</div>
```

```
var demoApp = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',    
    data: {
            selectedMedia: null,
            listAllMedia: [
                { code: "med1", label: "Media 1" },
              { code: "med2", label: "Media 2" },
                { code: "med3", label: "Media 3" },
              { code: "med4", label: "Media 4" },
              { code: "med5", label: "Media 5" },
              { code: "med6", label: "Media 6" },
              { code: "med7", label: "Media 7" },
              { code: "med8", label: "Media 8" },
        ],
        isMobile: false,
        characters: [
          { name: "A", medias:["med1", "med2", "med3"] },
          { name: "B", medias:["med2", "med4", "med8"] },
          { name: "C", medias:["med1", "med2", "med3"] },
          { name: "D", medias:["med1", "med8", "med6"] },
          { name: "E", medias:["med8", "med5", "med7"] },
                    { name: "F", medias:["med1", "med6", "med5"] },
          { name: "G", medias:["med7", "med4", "med3"] },
          { name: "H", medias:["med1", "med3", "med6"] },
          { name: "I", medias:["med5", "med6", "med8"] },
        ]
    },
    computed: {
        filteredListCharacters: function () {
            var self = this;
            var result = self.selectedMedia == null ? self.characters : self.characters.filter(x => x.medias?.includes(self.selectedMedia))
            
                        //what's bellow didn't work
            //const swiperEl = document.querySelector('swiper-container');
            //if (swiperEl != null) {                
            //    swiperEl.swiper.update();
            //}
            return result;
        }
    },
});
```

I've tried many things to correct the problem, including trying to force the slider to update using methods I found in the slider js documentation (https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api) or even removing several slider functions to get something really basic, but nothing changes (For exemple, I've removed the grid option, which makes everything even worse than it is now).

For your information, the way I initialized the breakpoints and other properties on my slider is the only way that worked for me, I saw that there were other ways of doing things but they didn't work. I don't know if this is important to note, as I think the problem comes from using a computed value to generate my slides, but I haven't yet figured out how to overcome this problem.

That's why I'm asking for your help to maybe put my finger on what's wrong.

Unfortunately, I can't remember everything I've tried, but don't hesitate to ask me if I've tried this or that solution and I'll tell you if I have, or if not, I'll try the proposal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to my problem. I modified the DOM as follows:

```
<swiper-container ref="swiper" :slides-per-view="isMobile ? 2 : 10"
                :space-between="isMobile ? 5 : 10"
                :centered-slides="false"
                :scrollbar="true" 
                :scrollbar-draggable="true" 
                :scrollbar-drag-size="isMobile ? 50 : 100" 
                :free-mode="true"
                
                breakpoints='{"100": {"slidesPerView": 2}, "480": {"slidesPerView": 3}, "650": {"slidesPerView": 4}, "850": {"slidesPerView": 5}, "950": {"slidesPerView": 6}, "1150": {"slidesPerView": 7}, "1300": {"slidesPerView": 8}, "1500": {"slidesPerView": 9}, "1700": {"slidesPerView": 10}}'>

 <template v-for="(chara, index) in filteredListCharacters">
  
    <v-card :slot="'slide-' + index" style="height: 300px; border: 1px solid black">

      <v-card-title style="color: black; padding-top: 10px;">{{chara.name}}
      </v-card-title>

      <v-card-text style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;">
        <div v-for="media in chara.medias" style="font-style: italic; color: gray; font-size: 10px;">{{listAllMedia.filter(x => x.code == media)[0]?.label}}</div>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>     
</template>  
</swiper-container>
```

I removed the **swiper-slide** tags and replaced it with **slot="slide-{index}"** on the child element and it works ! Here's the working jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Glow_Jr/0m4j51fL/52/

I found the solution here : https://swiperjs.com/blog/slide-slots-in-v10-1-0#solution